Local variable not destroyed at function end
So I have this LLVM-IR code:
; ModuleID = 'example.-.input.c'
source_filename = "example.-.input.c"

define ptr @test() {
entry:
  %0 = alloca ptr, align 8
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 2, ptr %1, align 4
  store ptr %1, ptr %0, align 8
  br label %ret

ret:                                              ; preds = %entry
  %2 = load ptr, ptr %0, align 8
  ret ptr %2
}

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %0 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, ptr %0, align 4
  %1 = call ptr @test()
  %2 = load i32, ptr %1, align 4
  store i32 %2, ptr %0, align 4
  br label %ret

ret:                                              ; preds = %entry
  %3 = load i32, ptr %0, align 4
  ret i32 %3
}


test returns a pointer to the local variable %1, a integer with the value of 2.
main calls test and extracts the integer from the pointer returned by test. But somehow main returns the "expected" value of 2 (%2 of main: pointed to %0 of test). But why? Shouldn't the local variable %0 be destroyed at the end of test and the pointer returnd by test then invalid?

When a local variable goes out of scope it isn't destroyed - it is just out of scope. The memory that it inhabited is still there and still contains its value, unless that memory has subsequently been used for something else. Dereferencing a pointer to such a variable is undefined behavior. You seem to expect that undefined behavior to be defined in a specific way.

So basically the meaning of undefined behavior, in this case, is that the memory of the pointed variable could change, leading to unexpected values, because the variable is out of scope?

That which you return is in scope. That which it points to is your business.

Dereferencing an out-of-scope pointer is undefined behavior. This means that the compiler is free to do anything in this case. The compiler chose to not erase that value from memory in this case. Do not rely on this behavior as it could change in the future.
